# How to construct new class in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to construct my Affiliation class. But when I try to use constructor I have `TypeError: Affiliation is not a constructor`
I think that comes from export but I don't understand how to do this, for me my export should be work.
here is my class :

```js
const {insertUpdateAffiliation} = require("../../interfaces/database/insert");

class Affiliation {
    /**
     *
     * @param {string} codeAffiliation
     * @param {string} colorAffiliation
     * @param {string} name
     */
    constructor(codeAffiliation,colorAffiliation,name) {
        this.codeAffiliation = codeAffiliation
        this.colorAffiliation = colorAffiliation
        this.name = name
    }

    async save(){
        await insertUpdateAffiliation(this)
    }
}

module.exports = {Affiliation}
```

here are my import and use of my class

```js
const {Affiliation} = require("../../models/starMap/Affiliation");

module.exports = {
    /**
     *
     * @returns {Promise<Array<Affiliation>>}
     */
    async getAffiliations(){
        let apiJSON = await get(`someURL`)
        apiJSON = JSON.parse(apiJSON)
        let affiliations = []
        for (const item of apiJSON.data) {
            affiliations.push(new Affiliation(item.code,item.color,item.name))//error here
        }
        return affiliations
    },
}
```

my file tree :

```
src
    ├───interfaces
    │   ├───database
    │   |       insert.js
    │   |
    │   └───restAPI
    │           here is where affiliation is call
    |
    └───models
        │
        └───starMap
                Affiliation.js
```

Comment: have you tried with export and import? also, whats the node version?

Comment: I'm in V12.18.0, I have try with import and export  but I have got `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` but it's probably because I don't use it correctly

Comment: add `"type": "module"` to your package.json. https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_package_json_type_field

Comment: oh ! It's just that ! Ok thanks ! But now I need to convert every required in my project to import :/

Comment: I can't use this solution because that makes a lot of trouble in my project... So if you have other ideas that really could help me